# Meteor.js + external Mongo. Meteor cannot login into Mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, meteor

I have a `meteor.js` app + `mongo db (2.6)`.

I've created a user in mongo like this:

```
use meteor
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "meteor",
    pwd: "password",
    roles:
    [
      {
        role: "userAdmin",
        db: "meteor"
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

here is my `mongodb.conf`:

```
dbpath=/data/db
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
logappend=true
port = 27017
```

when i set `auth = true` then my meteor app cannot connect to mongo anymore. It says

`Exception in callback of async function: MongoError: auth failed`

Same error when i try to connect with RoboMongo when auth is true. When auth is false i can connect with RoboMongo. So it's not about Firewall or something.

I don't understand, what I can do to switch on authorization in Mongo, so that it would let me login. Please help.

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but as of this writing I think meteor only supports up to mongo version 2.4.9 (at least thats what the [changelog](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md) indicates). I have seen other questions where people have indicated that 2.6.x fails to work.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you start Meteor. You need to tell it which Mongo instance to use and also provide proper credentials like this:

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db>
```

That's the way I've been doing it with my Meteor apps and a dedicated MongoDB and it works nicely. But if RoboMongo is not able to connect, there may be something wrong with the Mongo configuration. You can use this command to enable authentication in your config:

```
mongod --auth --config /path/to/mongodb.conf
```

I assume you have an admin user already which was used to create the meteor user, you will run into issues if you start Mongo without authentication, then add a meteor user anonymously and restart with auth=true.

Comment: right, i have that 
`MONGO_URL=mongodb://meteor:password@localhost:27017/meteor`
 in my upstart demon. It gives me that auth error.

And i have `auth=true` in mongodb.conf